# Response D3 Histogram Chart on Screen Size

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I have made a D3 histogram look responsive but I want it to be 100% responsive on any screen (div) resize. I think the idea is to calculate the diagonal of the parent div and use that to change the axis length accordingly. In this case below, The said idea calculates the horizontal size but I can not get it to recognize a vertical length and that messes up the horizontal resize.

```js
var color = "steelblue";

// Generate a 1000 data points using normal distribution with mean=20, deviation=5
var values = d3.range(1000).map(d3.random.normal(20, 5));
//var values = {{data}}

// A formatter for counts.
var formatCount = d3.format(",.0f");

var margin = {
    top: 30,
    right: 5,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 5
  },
  width = parseInt(d3.select("#histog").style("width")) - margin.left - margin.right
height = 275 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var max = d3.max(values);
var min = d3.min(values);
var x = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([min, max])
  .range([0, width]);

// Generate a histogram using twenty uniformly-spaced bins.
var data = d3.layout.histogram()
  .bins(x.ticks(20))
  (values);

var yMax = d3.max(data, function(d) {
  return d.length
});
var yMin = d3.min(data, function(d) {
  return d.length
});
var colorScale = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([yMin, yMax])
  .range([d3.rgb(color).brighter(), d3.rgb(color).darker()]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, yMax])
  .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bOkottom");

var svg = d3.select("#histog").append("svg")
  .attr("width", "100%")
  .attr("height", "26vh")
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var bar = svg.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "bar")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + x(d.x) + "," + y(d.y) + ")";
  });

bar.append("rect")
  .attr("x", 1)
  .attr("width", (x(data[0].dx) - x(0)) - 1)
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return height - y(d.y);
  })
  .attr("fill", function(d) {
    return colorScale(d.y)
  });

bar.append("text")
  .attr("dy", ".75em")
  .attr("y", -12)
  .attr("x", (x(data[0].dx) - x(0)) / 2)
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text(function(d) {
    return formatCount(d.y);
  });

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

/*
 * Adding refresh method to reload new data
 */
function refresh(values) {
  // var values = d3.range(1000).map(d3.random.normal(20, 5));
  var data = d3.layout.histogram()
    .bins(x.ticks(20))
    (values);

  // Reset y domain using new data
  var yMax = d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.length
  });
  var yMin = d3.min(data, function(d) {
    return d.length
  });
  y.domain([0, yMax]);
  var colorScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([yMin, yMax])
    .range([d3.rgb(color).brighter(), d3.rgb(color).darker()]);

  var bar = svg.selectAll(".bar").data(data);

  // Remove object with data
  bar.exit().remove();

  bar.transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + x(d.x) + "," + y(d.y) + ")";
    });

  bar.select("rect")
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return height - y(d.y);
    })
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
      return colorScale(d.y)
    });

  bar.select("text")
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .text(function(d) {
      return formatCount(d.y);
    });

}
```

```css
.histocontainer {
  float: right;
  width: 55%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  text-align: top;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .histocontainer {
    max-width: 540px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .histocontainer {
    max-width: 720px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .histocontainer {
    max-width: 960px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .histocontainer {
    max-width: 1140px;
  }
}

#scalesvg {
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<svg id="scalesvg">
       <div id=histog></div>
    </svg>
```

Comment: Before I even start to answer, can you explain why are you still using D3 v3? Then why you have a width of 20% (of available width) for the entire SVG? And why can't you just try to replace SVG width and height attribute with a viewBox to make the SVG automatically responsive to any size, with possible resize adjustment in code to potentially change font size or bar chart features?

Comment: You don't have to explain why you're still using D3 v3. You're hardly the only one on this website

Comment: I tried it both with just a standard viewbox svg and with the id for scaling. Neither has worked on my end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've simplified the example a bit and used the structure of your `refresh` function to create a `resize` function. I use [`window.addEventListener("resize")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to detect resizes and trigger the function.

All the stuff that can be done without knowing the width and height, I do outside the function, and inside I just redraw the bins and the axis.

It's all your code, I just moved it around a little.

```js
var color = "steelblue";

// Generate a 1000 data points using normal distribution with mean=20, deviation=5
var values = d3.range(1000).map(d3.random.normal(20, 5));

// A formatter for counts.
var formatCount = d3.format(",.0f");

var margin = {
  top: 30,
  right: 5,
  bottom: 20,
  left: 5
};

var max = d3.max(values);
var min = d3.min(values);
var x = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([min, max]);

var data = d3.layout.histogram()
  .bins(x.ticks(20))
  (values);

var yMax = d3.max(data, function(d) {
  return d.length
});
var yMin = d3.min(data, function(d) {
  return d.length
});
var colorScale = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([yMin, yMax])
  .range([d3.rgb(color).brighter(), d3.rgb(color).darker()]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, yMax]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom");

var svg = d3.select("svg")
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis");

function resize() {
  var rect = d3.select('svg').node().getBoundingClientRect();
  var width = rect.width - margin.left - margin.right;

  var height = Math.min(rect.height, window.innerHeight) - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  x.range([0, width]);
  y.range([height, 0]);

  // Reposition elements
  svg.select('x.axis')
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

  var bar = svg.selectAll(".bar").data(data);

  // Remove object with data
  bar.exit().remove();

  var newBars = bar.enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "bar");

  newBars.append("rect")
    .attr("x", 1);

  newBars.append("text")
    .attr("dy", ".75em")
    .attr("y", -12)
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")

  bar.transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + x(d.x) + "," + y(d.y) + ")";
    });

  bar.select("rect")
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr("width", (x(data[0].dx) - x(0)) - 1)
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return height - y(d.y);
    })
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
      return colorScale(d.y);
    });

  bar.select("text")
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr("x", (x(data[0].dx) - x(0)) / 2)
    .text(function(d) {
      return formatCount(d.y);
    });
}

window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
  console.log('resize!');
  resize();
});

resize();
```

```css
svg {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  text-align: top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```